# Daphne ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_name'

Tags: django, django-channels, daphne

When I run `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 --access-log=daphne.log config.asgi:application`
I get `Daphne ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_name'`

But when I run `python3 manage.py runserver` it works normally?
When I remove `app_1` from `INSTALLED_APPS` it will show me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_2'`

This is my folder structure:

```
project_name
│   __init__.py    
│   manage.py    
│ 
└───config
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   asgi.py
│   │   celery.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │
│   └───settings
│       │
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   base.py
│       │   dev.py
│       │   prod.py
│       
│
└───project_name
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───app_1
│   └───app_2
│   └───app_3
│   
└───media
│ 
└───static
```

`asgi.py`:

```
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application


django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

from chat import routing


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.dev')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: @SelvaPrasad Have you tried adding the project folder to the pythonpath env variable like so?
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/prassel/sml-266/simlai-api"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to append the folder where all my apps lie to the PYTHONPATH environment variable like so:
`PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/project_name/project_name"`

Answer (score 0):

just like this. **add a environment path to asgi.py**

```
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    import sys
    sys.path.append('your-project-abspath')
    import chat.routing
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'env.settings')

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http":get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

import django
django.setup()

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from notification.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

from notification.utils.websocket_auth import WebSocketAuthMiddleware

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": WebSocketAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns)
        ),
    }
)
```

In my case django setup fixed the problem.

just put django setup in asgi file.

Comment: For me `django.setup()` is what causes `No module named 'app_name'` when I run it on Docker container.