# Raspbian returns command not found when running sudo daphne

Tags: django, raspbian, sudo, django-channels, daphne

Goal is to run daphne on port 443.

When I run the following:

```
sudo daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=/etc/ssl/mycerts/apache.key:certKey=/etc/ssl/mycerts/apache.pem myProject.asgi:application
```

The following error is generated:

> sudo: daphne: command not found

running `which sudo` returns /usr/bin/sudo -- sudo is installed.

running `which daphne` returns /home/pi/.local/bin/daphne -- daphne is installed.

```
echo $PATH returns **/home/pi/.local/bin**:/lib/python3.9:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:**/usr/bin**:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So, both /usr/bin and /home/pi/.local/bin are on the path.

I can run daphne on port 8001 (without sudo) without any problems (ex. daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 myProject.asgi:application)

Why does the error command not found appear if sudo is installed, daphne is installed and both locations are on the PATH?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is when you sudo your executing the command as a different user (normally root) and `daphne` isn't on *that* user's path. Try `sudo /home/pi/.local/bin/daphne`.

Comment: That changed what I'm getting back as an error. New message is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/daphne", line 5, in <module>
    from daphne.cli import CommandLineInterface
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daphne'

Comment: I also tried adding the path to the PYTHONPATH (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093476/daphne-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-app-name) but that did not work either

Comment: It's hard to be able to say for sure exactly what issue is without more info, but that error is definitely python module path related (given you definitely can load daphne as non suod user). Try running a python interpreter directly and importing daphne as sudo and not as sudo. Check the module path when you can load it directly (`import daphne; print(daphne.__file__)`) then ensure that's in your python path before you sudo (`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:...; sudo ...`).

Comment: ran python as non-sudo and the path was /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Daphne/__init.py__. Added that to PYTHONPATH. After this, when I ran python as sudo, it came back with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'daphne'. I think I'm going to take a step back and see how other people are running daphne on ports < 1024. There has got to be a way. Thanks @spinkus for the help.